# Qual é a probabilidade do hash CRC32b se repetir?

Tags: hash

Qual é a probabilidade do *hash* CRC32b se repetir?

Por exemplo, duas strings diferentes retornarem o mesmo código:

```
echo hash('crc32b', 'Teste');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ele permite 2<sup>32</sup> combinações diferentes (pouco mais de 4 bilhões), então a probabilidade é nesta proporção, ou seja, 1 em ~4 bilhões.

Conforme vai tendo novos intens a comparar a probabilidade vai aumentando cada vez mais rápida, até que vai chegando aos bilhões de itens, onde o ritmo de crescimento da probabilidade diminui e chega a 100% quando tem 2<sup>32</sup>+1 itens usados. O gráfico:

[image: Probabilidade de colisão]

[Obtido aqui](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/) (tem a fórmula usada para chegar nele).

Lembrando que estamos falando de probabilidade, tudo podo acontecer, as únicas garantias é o 100% e o 0% (só tem 1 ou 0 itens).

Comment: O SHA-256 aguenta até 2^256 combinações diferentes. É um número que eu nem sei contar por extenso.